# 2002 Dodge Durango brake light

Tags: tail-lights

Driver brake light does not work. Bulb is good. Tried it in other side. Socket is good. tried it in other side. Tail light Assembly shows 12 volts. Brake light will not work. All other lights work. Help!!

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the contacts in the "bad" socket?

Comment: Yes I did. The "bad" socket works on the other brake light. thank you. good suggestion. Last time that was my problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you have cabling passing through a rubber boot from the body to the tailgate of a vehicle, the continual flexing of the wiring whilst opening and closing the tailgate can cause some of the wires in the cabling to break. Pull back the boot on your tailgate and if you find any of the wires seperated simply splice them back together. Same colour to same colour of course.